# How to make it look like the computer is typing?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want it to look like the computer is trying to type back to the user. I have tried some code, but when I run it, it just prints everything at 1 time even though I am printing it 1 at a time.

```
A = "Random sentence"
for x in A:
    time.sleep(random.randint(1,4))
    print(x, end='')
```

Comment: Using `pyautogui.typewrite` in the `pyautogui` module you can have the computer actually type...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `stdout.flush()`. This will force it to show up after every print.

```
import sys

A = "Random sentence"
for x in A:
    time.sleep(random.randint(1,4))
    print(x, end='')
    sys.stdout.flush()
```